# Windows: "syntax incorrect" -- can I ask Vim for the line number?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, error, line-numbers, windows

I use vim on Windows, using a "_vimrc" configuration file. When running the `vim` command in the prompt, I get the following error message before Vim starts every single time:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

As no line number is given, I have no clue to where to start to find why and where this happens. Is there a way to tell Vim to show error's line number?

Comment: this error/warning doesn't seem to be inside vims source code. Are you sure this is not caused by a plugin?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt It may very well be, but how may I identify that then? Plugins are also vimscript based and should be able to show internal errors, aren't they?

Comment: Followup: I use Vundle. I have disabled the plugins one by one to see if any of the error messages disappear, without any luck

Comment: note sure, try to debug your vimrc: https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5